# counting loop outputs where the number of outputs isn't fixed

Tags: python, count

this is my first question so be gentle.

I am making my first python project and as a learning process produced this code:

```
import random
count = random.randint(1,10)

print (count) ;

while (count < 9):

   print ('The count is:', count)

   count = random.randint(1,10)

print (count)
print ("Good bye!")
```

the labels are kind of strange as I adapted a basic teaching piece, the output when run obviously is the count is: number between 1-8 and repeats until you get a 9 then it stops, my question is, is there anyway to count the number of cycles before the random number is == 9?

Comment: Create another variable initialising it to 0 before the loop and increment inside the loop.

Comment: Add a `counter = 0` before your loop and increment this in your loop every iteration by `counter += 1`. Then `print(counter)`

Comment: thankyou very much guys excellent answers already got it working

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you two possible solutions:

1. The straightforward solution using a simple counter of cycles, as suggested by @Igle in comments:

   ```
   import random

   count = random.randint(1,10)
   print (count)

   nbOfCycles = 0
   while (count < 9):
       print ('The count is:', count)
       nbOfCycles += 1
       count = random.randint(1,10)

   print (count, "after", nbOfCycles, "cycles")
   print ("Good bye!")
   ```
2. The awesome solution appending each random values into a list. At the end, the number of cycles is the length of the list minus 1:

   ```
   import random

   count = [random.randint(1,10)]
   print (count[-1])

   while (count[-1] < 9):
       print ('The count is:', count[-1])
       count.append(random.randint(1,10))

   print (count[-1], "after", len(count)-1, "cycles")
   print ("Good bye!")
   ```